# Does Meteor.publish return old data when subscribe?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

In Microscope, [pagination part](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/blob/2bd56a61d23fcdf78fa676772a9e2371ec8d090a/lib/router.js#L10). `/10` will load 10 posts, `/20` will load 20 posts.

So first `subscribe('posts', {limits: 10})`, publish will return 10 posts, then
 `subscribe('posts', {limits: 20})`, publish will return all 20 posts, or only return new 10 posts?

Comment: your usage of subscribe seems a little off to me. The first argument must be the name of the subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor is clever enough to keep track of the current document set that each client has for each publisher. When the publisher reruns, it knows to only send the **difference** between the sets. Let's use the following sequence as an example:

1. subscribe for posts: `a,b,c`
2. rerun the subscription for posts `b,c,d`
3. server sends a `removed` message for `a` and an `added` message for `d`.

Note this will not happen if you stopped the subscription prior to rerunning it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, the question is basically: "does meteor resend records that are already on the client when re-subscribing". The answer to that is no and can be found in [Meteor docs for subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe)

> Meteor is smart enough to avoid wasteful unsubscribing/resubscribing